# Google Colab not showing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab for learning machine learning. I am a newbie to ML and haven't used colab. When I plot a figure using `matplotlib` it just shows the dimension and axis, but I want to see the figure.

When I tried to run my python program in colab it shows this:-
[image: 1]

This is the full code of finance regression:
[image: 2]

Comment: Images of code are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
!python finance_regression.py
```

Run script as follows:

```
%run finance_regression.py
```

It should show the plot.